# Eslint in Atom errors out on valid JSX syntax

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, jsx, eslint

At some point during the last two weeks eslint started to mark lines like these as errors, I am unable to pinpoint exactly what contributed to this.

My OS (Arch) was updated several times and package.json packages also suffered sporadic updates.

I had to even force Atom to recognize my JSX files correctly (with JSX grammar), since syntax highlighting for the default Javascript grammar got whacked too.

I have tried completely removing the atom package as well as config, but I am using Atom package `sync-settings` to backup and restore my configuration.

```jsx
return <InputFloat
  className='inline-block'
         ^^^^^^ Parsing error: Unexpected token = (Fatal)
  name={attribute.name}
  value={attribute.value}
  onChange={this.props.onChange}
/>
```

> Parsing error: Unexpected token = (Fatal)

**package.json**

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^5.9.0",
  "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
  "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
  "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```json
{
  "env" : {
    "browser": true,
    "node": false
  },
  "globals" : {
    "Module": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "standard"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 10,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "warn",
    "no-undef": 0,
    "no-path-concat": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "no-new-func": 0,
    "no-debugger": 0,
    "no-template-curly-in-string": "warn"
  }
}
```

**package-lock.json**

```json
  "eslint": {
    "version": "5.9.0",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-5.9.0.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-g4KWpPdqN0nth+goDNICNXGfJF7nNnepthp46CAlJoJtC5K/cLu3NgCM3AHu1CkJ5Hzt9V0Y0PBAO6Ay/gGb+w==",....
  }
```

**Atom**

> $ atom --version
>   Atom: 1.32.2 Electron: 2.0.12 Chrome: 61.0.3163.100 Node: 8.9.3

**Eslint**

> $ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --version 
>   v5.9.0

**Atom / linter-eslint**

> 8.4.1

**Atom Config**

> [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/david-polak/8ab10902208bc57b08870a333e73a804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps. Try install "[babel-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint)" and then add it `"parser": "babel-eslint",` to your .eslintrc.json file